# Статус отправки сообщения, отправленного через PHP mail()

Tags: email, php, exim

Здравствуйте.

Сталкивался ли кто нибудь с механизмом отслеживающим статус отправки сообщения, отправленного через PHP mail(). Как я понимаю надо отслеживать лог файл почтового сервера, в моем случае exim. Если кто то сталкивался, или что то делал, или есть идеи, подскажите куда копать.

Спасибо

Comment: Статус чего именно? если отправилось-неотправилось, то `mail` возвращает `boolean`

Comment: @thunder человеку нужно знать, дошло ли письмо или нет.

Comment: mail() возвращает встало ли письмо в очередь на отправку. Факт открытия можно отследить картинкой, в спам за это не кладут. Факт доставки как я понял вообще невозможно установить. А вот факт ОТПРАВКИ, то есть что домен принял письмо, что ящик существует, вот как это отследить?

Comment: Копайте в сторону DSN (Delivery Status Notification). Это механизм управления сообщениями о доставке почтовых сообщений. 

В протоколе ESMTP реализуется через параметр NOTIFY команды RCPT.
Так можно запросить у сервера, который непосредственно кладет сообщение в почтовый ящик получателя отправку на заданный адрес сообщения (письма) о доставке. Но учтите, это совершенно асинхронное по отношению к серверу-отправителю действие.

А вот как оформить это требование в PHP mail, я не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, что на ум приходит, - это конечно анализ логов. Но. Придется писать свою обертку для отсылки сообщений, плюс базу, поскольку для отслеживания по логам тебе придется где-то хранить `message id`.

Есть еще служебное поле `Disposition-Notification-To` которое можно задать в письме куда будет приходить отчет о доставке/ошибках, как я понимаю. Не пользовался, поэтому конкретно не скажу...

Есть еще забавный вариант, добавить в сообщение ссылку на изображение с `message id` типа `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/received_mail.php?id=mail_id">`, но это сработает если у пользователя незаблокирован вывод изображений...

Comment: Последний вариант: все нормальные почтовые сервисы либо помещают данные письма в спам, либо перезаливают картинку к себе. Вы же знаете прикол со смайлом?)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже писали **`true or false`**.